# Adding a string instead of a result 0 as result of a mysql SUM

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a query that extract from two tables the number of views of some users.
I'm struggling to find a way to show "n/a" when no results are found, so when the SUM is zero.

This are the two tables:

profiles:
- profile_id
- profile_name

views:
- profile_id
- date
- views

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    p.profile_name,
    Jan,
    Feb,
    Mar,
    Apr,
    May,
    Jun,
    Jul,
    Aug,
    Sep,
    Oct,
    Nov,
    December as 'Dec' 
FROM profiles p

LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
    profile_id,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 1,views,0)) As 'Jan',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 2,views,0)) As 'Feb',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 3,views,0)) As 'Mar',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 4,views,0)) As 'Apr',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 5,views,0)) As 'May',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 6,views,0)) As 'Jun',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 7,views,0)) As 'Jul',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 8,views,0)) As 'Aug',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 9,views,0)) As 'Sep',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 10,views,0)) As 'Oct',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 11,views,0)) As 'Nov',
    SUM(IF(MONTH(date) = 12,views,0)) As 'December'
    FROM views 
WHERE YEAR(date) = '2016'
GROUP BY profile_id) v
ON (p.profile_id = v.profile_id)
ORDER BY p.profile_name
```

I'm struggling to find a way to show "n/a" when no results are found.

This is the result I'm getting now:

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Profile        2016 | Jan    | Feb    | Mar    | Apr    | May    | Jun    | Jul    | Aug    | Sep    | Oct    | Nov    | Dec    |
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Anna Wintour        | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 649693 | 575615 | 658556 | 603785 | 588790 | 0      | 586767 | 639005 |
| Karl Lagerfeld      | 635900 | 626585 | 612628 | 586811 | 656580 | 536151 | 598911 | 646069 | 650960 | 594483 | 591757 | 683251 |
| Pierre Alexis Dumas | 629109 | 579499 | 647326 | 585578 | 597296 | 618063 | 603452 | 617052 | 586233 | 588641 | 604276 | 623885 |
| Sandra Choi         | 592426 | 590954 | 648027 | 564362 | 633135 | 612299 | 606808 | 629006 | 631480 | 680511 | 565733 | 573343 |
| Tom Ford            | 552798 | 603373 | 550430 | 709178 | 662036 | 608399 | 708395 | 610961 | 629205 | 628796 | 616628 | 712198 |
+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: So where are No Results Found?

Comment: I have added now the example with some 0 as result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display `N/A` when no views were found for a month, change each `SUM` to this form:

```
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN views END), 'N/A') As 'Jan',
```

This way, if there are no views for a month, the result of the `SUM` will be `NULL` (since the value of the `CASE` expression will be `NULL`), and the `COALESCE` will then turn that value into `N/A`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a739e2933ca86bb2806894f76999d9ec)

Comment: Amazing! I've just added a parenthesis before SUM, because it was missing and I was getting an error

Comment: @DavideCasiraghi actually I had accidentally put an extra parenthesis after the `SUM`. I edited it out about a minute ago :-P